# package [datetime] not working with [titling]

Tags: datetime, titling

Below is an SSCCE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{datetime}
%\usepackage{titling} %if this line is uncommented compilation fails

\begin{document}
\newdate{date2}{08}{02}{2015}
\date{\displaydate{date2}}
foo
\end{document}
```

... the above code compiles, but if the line that calls in the `titling` package is uncommented compilation fails with:

```
pdflatex esa-sre-gedais-sdp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./esa-sre-gedais-sdp.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fmtcount/fmtcount.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fmtcount/fc-english.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fmtcount/fc-USenglish.def)
No configuration file fmtcount.cfg found.
)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(./esa-sre-gedais-sdp.aux))
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 8.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> esa-sre-gedais-sdp.tex

? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on esa-sre-gedais-sdp.log.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what either package is doing, but if in doubt, add `\protect`. This runs without error:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{titling} %if this line is uncommented compilation fails

\begin{document}
\newdate{date2}{08}{02}{2015}
\date{\protect\displaydate{date2}}
foo
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` package has a peculiar choice of what commands should be robust or not. For instance, it declares `\longdate`, `\shortdate` and similar commands as robust (they shouldn't, probably), but it doesn't do the same to `\displaydate` which is likely to be used in moving arguments.

So the package *should* do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\displaydate}[1]{%
\@ifundefined{date@#1@y}{%
\PackageError{datetime}{Date `#1' not defined}{}}{%
\formatdate{\csname date@#1@d\endcsname}{%
\csname date@#1@m\endcsname}{%
\csname date@#1@y\endcsname}}}
```

because this command uses `\formatdate` which performs assignments and is not declared as robust when (re)defined (also `\PackageError` is a culprit). Unfortunately, the package uses `\newcommand` instead.

You can fix the issue with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{titling} %if this line is uncommented compilation fails

\robustify{\displaydate} % make \displaydate robust

\begin{document}
\newdate{date2}{08}{02}{2015}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\displaydate{date2}}

\maketitle

foo

\end{document}
```

and report this to the package author.

[image]